# Clear And Efficient 3D Range Tree Implementation

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, data-structures, range-tree

I'm working on this project where I have to search for objects in 3d space, and efficiency is a huge concern, I think **Range Tree** is perfect for what I'm trying to do, Interval Tree would also work but I'm not going to delete anything from the tree, once I add every object in 3D space, I'll only use the structure to do a search.

Here's how I'm going to use the structure:

Let say that I have an array(let's call it **queryArr**) of objects (~ 10,000 objects) each objects have 3 parameter (x,y,z) I have another very large array(let's call it **totalArr**) of objects ( > 5,000,000 objects).

What I'm trying to do here is given element of **queryArr**, find the most similar(or the same element in **totalArr**) In some cases there will be an object with the same parameters in **totalArr**, but in most cases, there won't be an object with same parameters.

So, I'll search all the values in between `(x+10,y+10,z+10)` and `(x-10,y-10,z-10)`. If it doesn't yield any result, I'll multiply x,y,z by 2 and try again until it yields some results.

The simplest way of doing this is a naive search method, which will have complexity of  `O(N*M) (N = size of queryArr, M = sie of totalArr)` but this method is incredibly slow and dumb.

I think Range Tree's is the way to go, but I have never implemented one myself and I don't quite understand how the range tree works on dimensions bigger than 2. So does anyone know a good implementation of the range trees? I believe if I can have a source code, I'll be able to understand how they really work.

By the way if you think, there is a better structure than Range Tree for this task, let me know I'm open to suggestions. (I have already considered kd-Trees and Interval trees)

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

I just read the wikipedia article.  Lets see if I can write an n dimensional range tree.  Because anything worth doing in 3 dimensions is worth doing in n.

So the basic part of an n-dimensional range tree is that it can be recursively defined in terms of lower dimensional range trees.

Some property classes to work with relatively generic value types.  Specialize `element_properties<T>` to set the scalar type of whatever your n-dimensional value is, and specialize `get<i>(T const&)` to get the `i`th dimension of your n-dimensional value.

```
#include <memory>
#include <cstddef>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

void Assert(bool test) {
  if (!test)
  {
    std::cout << "Assert failed" << std::endl;
    exit(-1);
  }
}
template<typename... Args>
struct Print {
  static void Do(Args... args) {}
};
template<typename Arg, typename... Tail>
struct Print<Arg, Tail...> {
  static void Do(Arg arg, Tail... args) {
      std::cout << arg;
      Print<Tail...>::Do(args...);
  }
};
template<typename... Args>
void Debug(Args... args) {
    std::cout << "DEBUG:[";
    Print<Args...>::Do(args...);
    std::cout << "]\n";
}

template<typename T>
struct element_properties {
  typedef typename T::value_type value_type;
};
template<>
struct element_properties<int> {
  typedef int value_type;
};
template<size_t d, typename T>
typename element_properties<T>::value_type get( T const & t );

template<size_t d>
typename element_properties<int>::value_type get( int i ) { return i; }

template<size_t d, typename U, typename A>
typename element_properties<std::vector<U,A>>::value_type get( std::vector<U,A> const& v) {
  return v[d];
}

template<typename T, size_t dim, typename Order = std::less< typename element_properties<T>::value_type> >
struct range_tree {
  typedef typename element_properties<T>::value_type value_type;
  struct sorter {
    bool operator()( T const& left, T const& right ) const {
      return Order()( get<dim-1>(left), get<dim-1>(right) );
    }
  };
  struct printer {
    std::string operator()( T const& t ) const {
      std::string retval = "[ ";
      retval += print_elements( t );
      retval += "]";
      return retval;
    }
    std::string print_elements( T const& t ) const {
      std::stringstream ss;
      typedef typename range_tree<T, dim-1, Order>::printer next_printer;
      ss << next_printer().print_elements(t);
      ss << get<dim-1>(t) << " ";
      return ss.str();
    }
  };
  template<typename Iterator>
  range_tree( Iterator begin, Iterator end ) {
    std::sort( begin, end, sorter() );
    root.reset( new tree_node( begin, end ) );
  }

  template<size_t n, typename Func>
  void walk(Func f) const {
      if (root) root->walk<n>(f);
  }
  template<size_t n, typename Func>
  void walk(Func f) {
      if (root) root->walk<n>(f);
  }
  struct tree_node {
    std::unique_ptr< range_tree<T, dim-1, Order> > subtree;
    T value;
    template<size_t n, typename Func>
    void walk(Func f) const {
      if (n==dim && !left && !right)
        f(value);
      if (left)
        left->walk<n>(f);
      if (right)
        right->walk<n>(f);
      if (subtree)
        subtree->walk<n>(f);
    }
    template<size_t n, typename Func>
    void walk(Func f) {
      if (n==dim && !left && !right)
        f(value);
      if (left)
        left->walk<n>(f);
      if (right)
        right->walk<n>(f);
      if (subtree)
        subtree->walk<n>(f);
    }
    void find_path( T const& t, std::vector< tree_node const* >& vec ) {
      vec.push_back(this);
      if ( sorter()(t, value) ) {
        if (left)
          left->find_path(t, vec);
      } else if (sorter()(value, t)) {
        if (right)
          right->find_path(t, vec);
      } else {
        // found it!
        return;
      }
    }
    std::vector< tree_node const* > range_search( T const& left, T const& right )
    {
      std::vector<tree_node const*> left_path;
      std::vector<tree_node const*> right_path;
      find_path( left, left_path );
      find_path( right, right_path );
      // erase common path:
      {
        auto it1 = left_path.begin();
        auto it2 = right_path.begin();
        for( ; it1 != left_path.end() && it2 != right_path.end(); ++it1, ++it2) {
          if (*it1 != *it2)
          {
            Debug( "Different: ", printer()( (*it1)->value ), ", ", printer()( (*it2)->value ) );
            break;
          }

          Debug( "Identical: ", printer()( (*it1)->value ), ", ", printer()( (*it2)->value ) );
        }
        // remove identical prefixes:
        if (it2 == right_path.end() && it2 != right_path.begin())
            --it2;
        if (it1 == left_path.end() && it1 != left_path.begin())
            --it1;
        right_path.erase( right_path.begin(), it2 );
        left_path.erase( left_path.begin(), it1 );
      }
      for (auto it = left_path.begin(); it != left_path.end(); ++it) {
        if (*it && (*it)->right) {
          Debug( "Has right child: ", printer()( (*it)->value ) );
          *it = (*it)->right.get();
          Debug( "It is: ", printer()( (*it)->value ) );
        } else {
          Debug( "Has no right child: ", printer()( (*it)->value ) );
          if ( sorter()( (*it)->value, left) || sorter()( right, (*it)->value) ) {
            Debug( printer()( (*it)->value ), "<", printer()( left ), " so erased" );
            *it = 0;
          }
        }
      }
      for (auto it = right_path.begin(); it != right_path.end(); ++it) {
        if (*it && (*it)->left) {
          Debug( "Has left child: ", printer()( (*it)->value ) );
          *it = (*it)->left.get();
          Debug( "It is: ", printer()( (*it)->value ) );
        } else {
          Debug( "Has no left child: ", printer()( (*it)->value ) );
          if ( sorter()( (*it)->value, left) || sorter()( right, (*it)->value) ) {
            Debug( printer()( right ), "<", printer()( (*it)->value ), " so erased" );
            *it = 0;
          }
        }
      }
      left_path.insert( left_path.end(), right_path.begin(), right_path.end() );
      // remove duds and duplicates:
      auto highwater = std::remove_if( left_path.begin(), left_path.end(), []( tree_node const* n) { return n==0; } );
      std::sort( left_path.begin(), highwater );
      left_path.erase( std::unique( left_path.begin(), highwater ), left_path.end() );
      return left_path;
    }

    std::unique_ptr<tree_node> left;
    std::unique_ptr<tree_node> right;
    // rounds down:
    template<typename Iterator>
    static Iterator middle( Iterator begin, Iterator end ) {
      return (end-begin-1)/2 + begin ;
    }
    template<typename Iterator>
    tree_node( Iterator begin, Iterator end ):value(*middle(begin,end)) {
      Debug( "Inserted ", get<dim-1>(value), " at level ", dim );
      Iterator mid = middle(begin,end);
      Assert( begin != end );
      if (begin +1 != end) { // not a leaf
        Debug( "Not a leaf at level ", dim );
        ++mid; // so *mid was the last element in the left sub tree 
        Assert(mid!=begin);
        Assert(mid!=end);
        left.reset( new tree_node( begin, mid ) );
        right.reset( new tree_node( mid, end ) );
      } else {
        Debug( "Leaf at level ", dim );
      }
      if (dim > 0) {
        subtree.reset( new range_tree<T, dim-1, Order>( begin, end ) );
      }
    }
  };
  std::unique_ptr<tree_node> root;
};
// makes the code above a tad easier:
template<typename T, typename Order >
struct range_tree< T, 0, Order > {
  typedef typename element_properties<T>::value_type value_type;
  struct printer { template<typename Unused>std::string print_elements(Unused const&) {return std::string();} };
  range_tree(...) {};
  struct tree_node {}; // maybe some stub functions in here
  template<size_t n, typename Func>
  void walk(Func f) {}
};

int main() {
  typedef std::vector<int> vector_type;
  std::vector<vector_type> test;
  test.push_back( vector_type{5,2} );
  test.push_back( vector_type{2,3} );
  range_tree< vector_type, 2 > tree( test.begin(), test.end() );
  std::cout << "Walking dim 2:";
  auto print_node = [](vector_type const& v){ std::cout << "(" << v[0] << "," << v[1] << ")"; };
  tree.walk<2>( print_node );
  std::cout << "\nWalking dim 1:";
  tree.walk<1>( print_node );
  std::cout << "\n";

  std::cout << "Range search from {3,3} to {10,10}\n";
  auto nodes = tree.root->range_search( vector_type{3,3}, vector_type{10,10} );
  for (auto it = nodes.begin(); it != nodes.end(); ++it)
  {
    (*it)->walk<2>( print_node );
  }
}
```

which is pretty damn close to an n-dimensional range tree.  The 0 dimension tree naturally contains nothing.

Basic facilities to search (in one dimension at a time) have been added now.  You can manually do the recursions into lower dimensions, or it up so that the `range_search` always returns level 1 `tree_node*`s.

Comment: Hi Yakk, Thank you for your answer, I'm trying to understand your code but I can't even compile it :( I tried to compile it with VC++ and MinGW but no dice. Is this code written in C++0x?, couple of things I'm confused about, first thing why would you want to remove identical prefixes? also what does **range_tree(...) {};** do when you call it? if it's not too much to ask would you explain your code a little bit? Thank you so much for your time and effort :)

Comment: The ... is just there to discard the arguments.  You may have to replace it with a do nothing constructor that takes two iterators.  The print and debug code is C++11 and will not compile in visual studio.  Removing identical prefixes is part of the algorithm to find a range -- Wikipedia explains it.