# All Sub Trees of a multiset

Tags: c++

I'm currently exploring `std::set` and `std::multiset`. I know that they are binary trees, But I was wondering if its possible to access the sub tree of a node which is sorted in `set` or `multiset`. For example, suppose that I have inserted (1,3,6,4,7,8,10,14,13) in a `set` and it looks like this:

[image]

Is it possible to find the sub tree of `3` which is `3,1,4,6,7`?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible - the Standard Library doesn't specify any functions in the [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) or [`std::multiset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset) APIs that give *any* indication of the internal node layout.

Comment: I'm trying to implement a 2d-Range tree, And I was wondering if I could use `std::set`instead of implementing a balanced binary tree from scratch, cause I think its more efficient to use the standard library tools. Is this possible?

Comment: @MoNo: I'm not sure... I know next to nothing about 2d-Range trees - not enough to guess at an implementation approach.  You're not the first to [ask about it on S.O.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15663914/implement-2d-range-tree-c) - there's mention of a (slow) implementation in comments.